# homepage keeps on redirecting to install.php

Tags: wordpress, mysql, database

I don't really have any clue what's causing this. It happened 3 times today already. The site that I'm assigned to work on keeps redirecting to http://atenews.ph/wp-admin/install.php

and when I tried checking my database on iPage Cpanel. I can't access any of the databases,  (also the old one that was used) shows this error

> 500 Error The page you requested no longer exists or is temporarily
>   unavailable. We apologize for this inconvenience. Please visit the
>   iPage homepage or use the links on this page to find the information
>   you need.
>
> If you think you reached this page in error, you can also ...
>
> Click your browser's Refresh button to try reconnecting to the
>   requested page. Check the spelling of the URL to make sure the address
>   is correct (capitalization and punctuation are important). Click your
>   browser's Back button to return to the previous page. If you have a
>   question or need assistance, please contact our Support Team.

Comment: You should add your "update" as an answer. You can then accept it (after a couple of days) to help inform others. Thanks.

Comment: By the way it's recommended to delete install.php file after you installed wordpress for security reasons. You may want to consider moving to WPEngine since it is the best hosting for wordpress needs around, before getting deep into iPage hosting services.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: iPage replied.

> We are sorry for the inconvenience caused you. Your account has
>   exceeded the MySQL query limit. This is the reason your website is
>   redirecting to the installation page. The best way to resolve this is
>   by making necessary changes to the website and making sure that your
>   website will not exceed the query limit.
>
> Also, you are able to purchase more query limit. To purchase query
>   limit 150k per hour, costs $20.00 / month .
>
> You can also consider upgrading to a WP Essential package to increase
>   the maximum number of queries allowed for your account. It costs $3
>   per month.